# Android Facebook Open Graph?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am curious if I can get some help with Open Graph since I can't seem to make any sense out of the Facebook API that I have read.

Right now I have setup my Open Graph Application on Facebook. It has been approved. I am trying to submit my "objects" via the bundle params but I am curious how I setup a bundle param object like the following. Where **myObject** has multiple values associated with it.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
param.putString("myObject", ""); // My object has multiple values
```

I guess I really need to figure out how you submit something in the Bundle that has multiple properties associated with it. If anyone has any insight on this please help me out.

At first I had tried something like this.

```
Bundle myObject = new Bundle();
myObject("property1", "property1Value");
myObject("property2", "property2Value");
myObject("property3", "property3Value");
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("myObject", myObject);
```

But in hindsight I figured out why this wouldn't work.

**Edit 1**

Maybe this will shed some light. Keep in mind this is an Open Graph action which is not a part of the Graph API.

```
//Build recipe
JSONObject recipe = new JSONObject();
recipe.put("type", "myappns:recipe");
recipe.put("recipe_name", "Thai Island");
recipe.put("cook_time", "1hr. 30min.");

//Build cookbook
JSONObject cookbookParams = new JSONObject();
cookbookParams.put("type", "myappns:book");
cookbookParams.put("title", "Hot & Spicy");
cookbookParams.put("description", "This book consists of hot & spicy foods");
cookbookParams.put("recipes", new JSONArray().put(recipe));


Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("cookbook", cookbookParams.toString());
AsyncFacebookRunner request = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
request.request("me/myappns:used", params, "POST", new addToTimelineListener(), null);
```

Here is a question though as I have been digging more into the Open Graph system. I believe I need to actually have a website setup somewhere, is this correct? I was lead to believe through the introductory documentation of Open Graph that I could create and use my Facebook application on Android without the need of any website. That is use the Open Graph system, I know I can use the application to post feeds and what not which I have done successfully.

Thanks again!

**Edit 2**

Dont even worry about replying I understand what my problem was now...I have to have a website somewhere hosting a Facebook application for the posts to link back too. Makes perfect sense, I haven't seen where the documentation was very direct about this...oh well now I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code to publish on wall for multiple object properties.

```
     private void publishPhoto(String imageURL) {
    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "Post to Facebook!");

    try {

        JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();
        attachment.put("message",text);
        attachment.put("name", "MyGreatAndroidAppTest");
        attachment.put("href", "http://stackoverflow.com/users/909317/sunny");
        attachment.put("description","Test Test TEst");

        JSONObject media = new JSONObject();
        media.put("type", "image");
        media.put("src",  imageURL);
        media.put("href",imageURL);
        attachment.put("media", new JSONArray().put(media));

        JSONObject properties = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject prop1 = new JSONObject();
        prop1.put("text", "Text or captionText to Post");
        prop1.put("href", imageURL);
        properties.put(text, prop1);

        // u can make any number of prop object and put on "properties" for    ex:    //prop2,prop3

        attachment.put("properties", properties);

        Log.d("FACEBOOK", attachment.toString());

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
        facebook.dialog(MyProjectActivity.this, "stream.publish", params, new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                if (postId != null) {
                    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "Dialog Success! post_id=" + postId);
                    Toast.makeText(MyProjectActivity.this, "Successfully shared on Facebook!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "No wall post made");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });      

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("FACEBOOK", e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I think this is working but I am getting the following error, any advice: {"error":{"message":"(#3503) \"{\"property1\":\"property2\",\"property3\":\"property4\"}\" is an invalid value for property \"myObject\" with type \"Reference\"","type":"OAuthException","code":3503}}

Comment: Ok I am obviously just formatting my data incorrectly, Open Graph is so confusing with no examples for Android. I am going to accept your answer and then also post how I was able to incorporate the Open Graph with this, once I get it.

Comment: Sunny I still am having trouble with this do you have any insight? I am still getting the same error above.

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy Please ask a separate question and I'll answer it.

Comment: @Sunny check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472897/android-how-to-share-data-with-facebook-open-graph-in-new-sdk-3-0

Answer (score 1):

To see a complete example look at the [wishlist example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/samples/).

A complete example for Android is included. The package includes the files to be uploaded on the server and a readme file that explain how to set up all the stuff on the open graph panel.