# android and facebook - Posting a custom action to a users wall

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Ive been reading up on the latest version of the facebook sdk and Im having a little trouble figuring out how to create a custom action on facebook and then posting to it from the android device. Id like to post a users location along with a photo and a description using the latest 3.0 version of their sdk. Ive seen plenty of examples doing what Im trying using the older version of their sdk but theyve marked a lot of it as depreciated. Any help other than "read the documentation" would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can post images with that information using a regular POST request through the Facebook API. According to [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) , you can pass values for "message", "place".

If you really want to create a custom object - use the FB OpenGraph. Create a new action type , eg. "share" and new object type "geo_picture". Then do a post using your new object type [facebook open-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966859/android-facebook-open-graph)
Unfortunately, you will have to create a page for your custom Object, as explained in [Step 4 here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) .

Comment: ahhhh I think I missed the part on creating a page. I had already created a custom action but I couldnt figure out how to add a photo, a location, and some text to the action and make it display on a users wall.

Comment: Also, don`t forget that you need to submit the action from your OpenGraph Dashboard (on the right side). Otherwise the action will be available to admins and developers of the app only.

Comment: Yeah that much I know lol I just havent stream lined the process of getting it to work at the moment

Comment: So after doing some reading I dont think I can do what I want. I have to set up the photo on my server and then use that url in my object and I dont want to do it that way. I would rather just serve the image to facebook encapsulated in an object or something like that.

Comment: Had exactly the same experience and reached the exact same conclusion. Naturally, you could pass the image to your server and deal with it from there, so you the question becomes - how bad do you really need a custom implementation...